# Angular - set selected key from controller

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-controller

This is my combo box:

```
<select  data-ng-model="data.selectedChannel" 
data-ng-options="salesChannel.value for salesChannel in salesChannels">
</select>
```

on my controller I have a function which calls a factory that goes away and get a key via web service for example say the key is called "HIRE". My combo box has a few options and one of them has the key of "HIRE".

Now in my controller how do I set the key so that my combo selects that option?

I thought it would be something like this:

```
$scope.data.selectedChannel.key = "HIRE";
```

But that doesnt seem to work.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate, I wanted someone to point our where the problem was in my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this  Way

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.data.selectedChannel.length;i++)
{
  if($scope.data.selectedChannel[i].key=='HIRE')
  {
    $scope.data.selectedChannel = $scope.data.selectedChannel[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the => gives me a "syntax error on token ">", delete this token" error (using eclipse). And if i remove that I get an "ReferenceError: f is not defined" on my console (on my browser).

Comment: I have update the answer

Comment: Still no luck :(  Nothing seems to happen.

Comment: I did a break point on the for loop, and the .length shows as undefined

Comment: problem fixed changing this worked: 

data-ng-options="salesChannel.key as salesChannel.value for salesChannel in salesChannels">

and then setting $scope.data.selectedChannel = "HIRE";